# How to substitute a partial string?

Tags: sql-server, substitution

thank you in advance for your help.
I would like to remove a partial string from a select query in which there is the legend "ProcessError : Lens " followed by 12 numerical digits and substitute those 12 digits by dashes.
I'm adding the result of the current query's result:

```
          Error Description
 ProcessError : Lens 000300084502 is defect/scrap lens! 
 ProcessError : 20007  rejected 
 ProcessError : Lens 046000085174 is defect/scrap lens! 
 ProcessError : Lens 011900085176 is defect/scrap lens! 
 ProcessError : Lens 001200085188 is defect/scrap lens! 
 ProcessError : 20006  operation canceled 
 ProcessError : Lens 000300085787 is defect/scrap lens!
```

Thank you and have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming no more than one key string per record, you can use patindex() in concert with `stuff()`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Error Description] varchar(150))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('ProcessError : Lens 000300084502 is defect/scrap lens!')
,('ProcessError : 20007')
,('ProcessError : Lens 046000085174 is defect/scrap lens!')
,('ProcessError : Lens 011900085176 is defect/scrap lens!')
,('ProcessError : Lens 001200085188 is defect/scrap lens!')
,('ProcessError : 20006')
,('ProcessError : Lens 000300085787 is defect/scrap lens!')
 
Select *
      ,NewVal = IsNull(stuff([Error Description]
                       ,patindex('%Lens [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', [Error Description])
                       ,17
                       ,'Lens ------------'
                 ),[Error Description])
 from @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
Error Description                                       NewVal
ProcessError : Lens 000300084502 is defect/scrap lens!  ProcessError : Lens ------------ is defect/scrap lens!
ProcessError : 20007                                    ProcessError : 20007
ProcessError : Lens 046000085174 is defect/scrap lens!  ProcessError : Lens ------------ is defect/scrap lens!
ProcessError : Lens 011900085176 is defect/scrap lens!  ProcessError : Lens ------------ is defect/scrap lens!
ProcessError : Lens 001200085188 is defect/scrap lens!  ProcessError : Lens ------------ is defect/scrap lens!
ProcessError : 20006                                    ProcessError : 20006
ProcessError : Lens 000300085787 is defect/scrap lens!  ProcessError : Lens ------------ is defect/scrap lens!
```